# How to get points that belong to the selected area in highcharts?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a line graph in [Highcharts](https://www.highcharts.com/). What I am currently building is to get the points belonging to the selected area when I zoom the line graph by drag and drop.

[image]

If I select the area from zero to any time (e.g. 02:00), then it should zoom the selected area.

Here's the highchart config.

```
let options = {
  ...
  xAxis: {
    type: 'datetime',
  },
  chart: {
    zoomType: 'x',
    events: {
      selection: (event) => {
        if (event.resetSelection) {
          this.$nextTick(() => {
            console.log(event.target.xAxis[0].min, event.target.xAxis[0].max)
            this.range = null
            this.update()
          })
        } else {
          console.log(event.xAxis[0].min, event.xAxis[0].max)
          this.range = [event.xAxis[0].min, event.xAxis[0].max]
          // [1663201200530.95 1663207868319.1133]
          this.update()
        }
      },
    },
  },
}

const update = () => {
  // There are no data points that belong to the selected area
  const filterData = data.filter(item => !this.range || (this.range &&
    new Date(item.timestamp).getTime() >= this.range[0] &&
    new Date(item.timestamp).getTime() <= this.range[1]
  ))

  const newData = filterData.map((item) => {
    return {
      x: new Date(item.timestamp), // 1663079619410
      y: Number(item.score), // 28.28
    }
  })

  const serieses = [{
      data: newData,
      zoneAxis: 'x',
      zones: newData.map((element) => ({
        value: element.x
      })),
    },
    ...
  ]

  options[series] = serieses
}
```

As you can see in the image, the data point should be visible and zoomed in when I select the area, but I can't see any data points after selection.

The specific reason to set the selection event is that I need to get the count number of points in any visible area.

Please let me know what is the issue.

Comment: Could you please reproduce your issue in the online editor that we could work on? You can start here: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/n84s0k5r/ Thanks!